# I don't know how this lambda function works

Tags: python

```
def run_lambda_check():
    """This function help me to input run in one line and i know its not the best way to do it"""
    run = True
    while run:
        run = (lambda check: True if check == "y" else False)(input("Do you want to draw more? "))
```

I'm working on making my first simplified python game, blackjack to be exact. The code i've made is just, hurts my eyes.
Thats why im trying to fix it by make it with less lines or make it become more readable. In this case im trying to reduce the number of lines. To be honest i dont feel comfortable doing this again and again whenever i want to ask user if they want to continue doing something or not. (because the code is hard to read, tbh i dont know this will work before i tried to write and fix it)
So my question is, there are better ways to do it in one line, can you guys show me any of it which u usually use in reality, or should i just make a function to do this alone?

Comment: If it works, it's better to post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Fewer lines" is not even close to the same as "more readable".

Comment: As you can see, shorter code is not necessarily easier to read.

Comment: "there are better ways to do it in one line", No, you'd be doing yourself a much better service by stopping trying to fit everything into the smallest possible box

Comment: You could do something like `while (input("Do you want to draw more? ") == "y"): pass` which saves you lines but it looks worse.

Comment: Hard to see what the point is of your lambda function.

Comment: The title of your question is quite different than what you ask in the text itself. Do you want an explanation of your current code? Or do you want an example of clearer code that does the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for your helps and comments guys. I'm a beginner so i know myself have many things to fix. I think i got what i need from posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code might be ameloriated to not use lambda at all following way

```
def run_lambda_check():
    run = True
    while run:
        run = (input("Do you want to draw more? ") == "y")
```

Observe that `==` comparison already gives `True` or `False` so there is not need to wrap it inside ternary operator.

Comment: More fun with `while (input("Do you want to draw more? ") == "y"): pass`. Removes the `run` variable. But again, as before, probably less readable.

Comment: If you want to be *really* terse, `for x in iter(input, "y"): pass` :)